# How to change the size of the column of my tree

Tags: odoo-8

how i can add width for all fields of my tree

```
<field name="line_ids" widget="one2many_list" string='Lots'>
                            <tree  create="false" delete="false"  editable="buttom">
                                <field name="name_lot" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="id_article_line" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="qtite_contratl" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="qtite_cumulel" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>    
                                <field name="qtitel"/>  
                            </tree>
                    </field>
```

Comment: You probably mean "column", not "colone"

Comment: yes answer me....???

Comment: I don't know `odoo-8`, but you'll better correct the typo in your title.

Comment: Can not anyone help me ??